Как правильно обновлять цены на товары, что бы не изменилась цена прошлых продаж?
Например, в базе храниться стол цена 500 руб. Его купили уже некоторые клиенты, и мы хотим обновить цену на 800 руб или какое-то другое поле у стола. Но как оставить у уже купивших людей этот стол с характеристиками товара именно в момент покупки. То что цена новая они могут это видеть и купить снова по новой цене. В случае отказа от покупки вернуть им стоимость по той цене которую они купили. Если они успели убрать товар в корзину за 500 руб, то стоимость стола и остается 500 руб.
Можно, пожалуйста, на примере субд PSQl и диаграмму


храните номинальную стоимость товара там где храните информацию о покупке 2) храните реальную цену (например номинал минус промо) там где храните информацию о покупке


это как ? Можете объяснить на схеме. Вы двух предложения пишете одно и тоже "где храните информацию о покупке"

вы пишете Но как оставить у уже купивших людей этот стол с характеристиками товара именно в момент покупки. значит покупка как-то фиксируется у вас в БД. значит я должен телепатически угадать как у вас это хранится? или просто нарисовать за вас весь сервис?

Этот вопрос у меня возник теоретически. А что если измениться цена товара который уже купили. Что тогда произойдет, ведь измениться по цепочки цена всего. Поэтому никого сервиса нет. А вопрос в том как с этим борются и что для этого есть

как в вашем теоретическом приложении хранится информация по покупке товара?

клиент многие ко многим к товару через таблицу заказ. А в таблице заказ имеет boolean оплачено или нет

ну представьте что у вас "Заказ" - "Позиция заказа" (тут фиксировать номинал) - "Товар"

Позиция заказа это ещё одна сущность/таблица?

ага____________

а какие у них отношения ? многие ко многим через таблицу "Позиция заказа". Или заказ один ко многим Позиция заказа. Позиция заказа один ко многим Товар
